# AWS API Gateway Export is exporting an older version

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I created an API Gateway with AWS CDK with a resource and a request model:

```js
const api = new apigateway.RestApi(this, 'MyApiGateway', {
  deploy: true,
  retainDeployments: false
});

const createDto = api.addModel('CreateUserDto', {
  modelName: 'CreateUserDto',
  schema: ...
});

const users = api.root.addResource('users');
users.addMethod(
  'POST',
  createUserLambdaIntegration, {
    operationName: 'Create User',
    requestModels: {
      'application/json': createDto
    },
    methodResponses: [
      {
        statusCode: '201'
      }
    ]
  }
);
```

then I changed it by adding a response model and changing the name of the request model:

```js
const api = new apigateway.RestApi(this, 'MyApiGateway', {
  deploy: true,
  retainDeployments: false
});

const createUserRequest = api.addModel('CreateUserRequest', {
  modelName: 'CreateUserRequest',
  schema: ...
});

const createUserResponse = api.addModel('CreateUserResponse', {
  modelName: 'CreateUserResponse',
  schema: ...
});

const users = api.root.addResource('users');
users.addMethod(
  'POST',
  createUserLambdaIntegration, {
    operationName: 'Create User',
    requestModels: {
      'application/json': createUserRequest
    },
    methodResponses: [
      {
        statusCode: '201',
        responseModels: {
          'application/json': createUserResponse
        }
      }
    ]
  }
);
```

this all works somewhat fine, as I am able to see the updated models on the API Gateway console, but when I try exporting the API as a Swagger JSON, it always exports the first version I deployed. I tried exporting it using both the API Gateway console and the AWS CLI with the exact same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where's the code that defines your API stage?

Comment: I don't define a stage, I just use the default one which is created as "prod"